# How to mention rpm to look for dependent perl modules in the system

Tags: linux, perl

By default rpm looks for the perl modules inside the rpm itself and throws dependency error if it is not found.
For eg., I have a perl script in the rpm that uses `Crypt::DES` perl module.
I have that perl module in the system (`/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Crypt/DES.pm` ) and this directory is included in `@INC`
When I try to install the rpm package:

`[jai@orange x86_64]$ rpm -ivh abc-1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

`error: Failed dependencies:`

`...(some other perl modules)`

`perl(Crypt::DES) is needed by abc-1.el6.x86_64`

`...(some other modules)`

But when I put that perl module (DES.pm ) inside the source of the rpm, it doesn't show the dependency error for that perl module.

And my question is how to specify in rpm (may be in spec file) to look for perl dependencies in the system also?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to include something like below in your spec file:

```
Requires:   perl(Crypt::DES)
```

See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-specfile-syntax.html#id729642

You may also want to see if your distro provides a perl-Crypt-DES package and use that instead of manually putting the files under /usr/local/